# RESTful API: Should I send URI parts in the response body? And how about Updating them?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am building a `RESTful` API and I am not sure whether it is a problem (and violation of REST) to send information that is the same as `URI` parts in the response `body` or not.

### Current Situation

An `GET` `/element/$ID` call gets you data of this element from the database, which also contains the `element_ID` and with that the last part of the `URI`. Right now clients are using `element_ID` from the body, but changing them would be no problem, *if it should not be this way in a `RESTful API`*.

### General Question

**Is it a problem to send `URI` parts in the response body?**
(and if so should these parts be changeable)
Should the data be removed from the response body so clients have to use the `URI` to extract needed information? The main problem (additional to unnecessary overhead because of redundancy) I see is when clients want to change fields relevant for building the `URI` (e.g. use `PUT` on `/element/$ID` and change the `element_id` field).

### Examples

Would this be a problem (the `element_id` is also used for the `URI`):

```
{
    "name": "Robert",
    "element_id": 1337
    "links": [ {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://domain.tld:8080/element/1337"
    } ]
}
```

And what would happen if you make following call on this model

```
PUT http://domain.tld:8080/element/1337
{
    "name": "Robert",
    "element_id": 1234
}
```

Or should the model just look more like this?

```
{
    "name": "Robert",
    "links": [ {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://domain.tld:8080/element/1337"
    } ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this question is considered "opinion-based": if you see all the answers fundamentally agree, and show references (and all the answers reference basically to the same...!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow the HATEOAS constraint, clients should use URI's provided by the server to "dinamically navigate Rest interfaces".

So, if you provide this "element_id", you not violate HATEOAS constraint, but **your client will violate it** if it uses that to construct his URI's in place of use that provided by the server.

To don't give that chance to clients it will be better to consider that identification an "internal" and don't include it in the document. But in some cases you could use relevant element information (i.e. "user name") to construct the URI and you must include that.

The important point is that the client should not try to construct the URIs, to access the API.

The benefit of it is to allow reorganization or amplification of the Rest interface without the need to modify the client, for example tomorrow you could want to group elements in projects (to say something) and want to change your href to

"http://domain.tld:8080/project/01/element/1337"

if your client followed HATEOAS it will need no changes.

Comment: Thank you very much! But the usage of `PUT` is still unclear for me in this case.
(Following your argumentation of your third paragraph.) If the relevant element information is in the body, and the client calls a `PUT` on `http://domain.tld:8080/element/$ID` where he changes the `element_ID` to `$newID`, how should the API respond to that to behave RESTful?

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I haven't seen that 1337 vs. 1234 point... For, me it has to reject the update and return an error. It's similar to a common pattern in Rest used to avoid  conflicting updates to send a token in the document (that changes in each update of that resource) that has to be matched for the update to be accepted (see an example in CouchDB database [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#PUT) )

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! So just to double check: To update a field which is critical for the URI you have to first `GET /$ID`, then `DELETE /$ID`, and then `POST`<XOR>`PUT /$newID` (with changed field), right?

Comment: No, it is not required to delete the resource at all. What is usually required is only to allow updates if you first has the most recent version of the resource. And to assure that is required to send back that version-specific token.

Comment: For general updating I did understand that, I think. But I meant for problems like the "element_ID 1337 vs 1234 point" where the specific field is relevant for the element URI...

Comment: The server must reject any update with detected incoherent information. If a resource "http://domain.tld:8080/element/1337" must have a element_ID=1337 you should reject any PUT that does not verify that. But only include that information in the content if your client needs it for something. If not you are only generating unnecessary complications.

Comment: The only ID that the client should use as an ID is the href, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570)

- if you want the user to fill in some parameters with input fields.
- if you want to make your response smaller, but that is much easier with gzip

You should follow the HATEOAS principle: the clients should not break if you change the URI structure. So roughly the client should not build URIs, or if it builds URIs, then always the server gives the recipes how to do it, so if the recipes change, the client can adapt. This is very similar to how browsers work, they follow links given by the HTTP server...

Comment: Thank you very much @inf3rno! Upvoted. But as it seems my question was not very clear, when I first wrote it. Our clients will not try to build the `URIs`. The question I have is more about including redudant URI information in the response body and the behavior when clients try to change this "URI-critical" fields via `PUT`.

Comment: It is still hard to understand what you are asking... The clients should not parse the URIs to get information, because URIs can change, and such a change would break an URI parser client. The server does not need the element id by a PUT request, because it can parse the URIs, and get the id from there. So the element id in your case is a read only property.

Maybe you are confused about PUT - for full update and PATCH - for partial update thing. I think these definitions are about writable fields...

Comment: ||edit: whoops, now your answer is longer. || Oh. my bad. Let my try again. I use the field (among other things) `element_ID` (from the DB) to build the REST URIs of `elements`. Now two questions. 1) Should I still include `element_ID` in the response body of an `element` GET call? (its redudant. client could extract it from the URI) 2) How should a client be able to update the `element_ID` field of an element (this will change its REST URI)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! (which I saw afterwards) This explains a lot for me for my question `1)` in the last comment. Do you also have a suggestion for my second question (how to update the id field via client)?

Comment: If you want to update the element id, just send a PUT request to the old URI, which contains the new id. After that you can send back a 200 ok with the new URI.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i understand your question entirely. However, including URI's to objects in your response is a constraint of REST called HATEOAS. Have a look here: http://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS

Response formats are not a concern of REST.

Comment: thanks for your reply and the link! I see, my question was not very clear, so I added a example to the question. I am not talking about sending the "whole URI" but the last part of it (because its the id in the DB...)